# Update weight synchronously from digital scale DLL file C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, dll, class-library

I have built a software which retrieve the weight from digital scale and output it in a label in WinForms. Every time the weight changes in the scale it is also  automatically updated in the label. Successfully I made it.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            port.DtrEnable = true;
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            port.Open();
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                label1.Text = port.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, my boss asked me to implement this code in a .DLL file (Class Library). He just wants to add as a reference, call the class and it returns the weight and also it updates automatically.
He just wants to make a simple call on Page Load like this sample:

```
Scale sc = new Scale();
label1.text = sc.weight();
```

I can successfully return the weight but it does not updated automatically via the Class Library and this is the code I am using in my Class Library (.DLL file):

```
public class Scale
    {
        SerialPort port;

        public string weight()
        {
            try
            {
                port = new SerialPort(com, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

                if (port.IsOpen == false)
                {
                    port.Open();
                }

                port.DtrEnable = true;

                return port.ReadLine();;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope I was explained clearly. Any help with the code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to look into data binding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have binded an event on port.DataReceiver in you WinForms application but your class library does not support the same. The classlibrary only return the string once to the calling code.

I guess there are ways to raise events in the class library, but I guess the calling code needs to listen to the events.

Comment: So is this possible? If Yes, do you have any idea with the code because I am not figuring out how to do this for 3 days. :/

Comment: I think it might be possible to do with the observer pattern. But you will not be able to call it in this way Scale sc = new Scale();
label1.text = sc.weight();. You would need to do something like Scale sc = new Scale(); ScaleObservable observable = new ScaleObservable(sc); ScaleObserver sc = new ScaleObserver(observable); when calling the class library. Then you will be able to handle the events from the SerialPort in a better way. Here is a good sample you can run in a console app: http://www.masnun.com/2012/04/13/implementing-the-observer-pattern-in-c-code-samples.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try if I can do it. Thank you for the explanation. :)